# Why Must Variables used in Guarded Pattern Case Labels be Final/Effectively Final? (Java 21)

Tags: java, switch-statement, language-lawyer, java-21, switch-expression

With the new Java 21 features, we have better [Pattern Matching](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441). With these features, we have guarded pattern case labels, where one can define a pattern guard for case labels that looks like the following:

```
switch (someObject) {
    case String s when someVar == 5 -> {}
    case Integer i when someVar == 10 -> {}
    //...//
}
```

Why, in the example above, must `someVar` be final or effectively final? Is it so that we can't reassign the value in a seperate case that would make our case pass/fail differently than if we had not reassigned it? I could not find the relevant information digging through the JEP but if someone can point me to it that'd be great!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Comment: The guards must be boolean expressions, `someVar == 5`...

Comment: Not clear to me why it is so, I can't find a case where it would cause any problem. Maybe related to dominance? I added language-layer tag.

Comment: Because the meaning of the switch -- which is code -- should be constant.  It should not be sensitive to changes in the values of local variables.  Of course, you are free to blow this up using calls to methods whose behavior changes from invocation to invocation -- thank you, pervasive mutability -- but you shouldn't.

Comment: @tevemadar Thanks for the guidance, but no unfortunately that doesn't seem to answer the question. That deals with closures, which I don't think is what is happening here. They were wanting to use a variable inside an anonymous class, in which case the answers go into why that variable must be final

Comment: @BrianGoetz You say it should be constant, but is it defined or specified anywhere that is has to be? I can understand why it is best practice, but this is a compile error: `java: local variables referenced from a guard must be final or effectively final`

Comment: @Idalas it has been written now, directly above your comment. Brian Goetz is one of the developers making this decision so if he says, that’s the reason they decided that way, you can trust him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the meaning of the switch -- which is code -- should be constant. It should not be sensitive to changes in the values of local variables. Of course, you are free to blow this up using calls to methods whose behavior changes from invocation to invocation -- thank you, pervasive mutability -- but you shouldn't.  Doing so makes switches harder to understand (and harder to optimize.)